# Do you lose all your items, or just the loot, if you're too greedy at the end of Harran prison quest?

Tags: dying-light

The repeatable mission Harran Prison ends with a room full of loot. However, the room has a one minute timer. If you're not out of there before the timer elapses, you die.

The internet sources are not entirely clear on what you lose upon death. Do you lose all items or only the items looted in the last room?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the following (hah!) comments:

> Be sure that you leave the armory (step toward the exit door) before the timer runs out, or else you die and **lose everything**. Players that try to be too greedy will suffer in the end with absolutely nothing even after making it this far. The time stops the moment that Crane stands in front of the exit door - nearly touching it. The door will seal off in the back of Crane once he is in position to where the timer stops.
>   <sup>[source](https://www.neoseeker.com/dying-light/walkthrough/Harran_Prison)</sup>

and

> if you run out of time, the door will seal and the room will detonate.
>   This instantly kills you, but even worse, **it removes all the loot you
>   picked up that run**. Sometimes, it's best to cut your losses and save
>   what you have.
>   <sup>[source](https://gameplay.tips/guides/2700-dying-light.html)</sup>

and

> I died at the end and got nothing. **The loot I managed to
>   pick up disappeared** and I would have to redo the whole thing.
>   <sup>[source](https://www.reddit.com/r/dyinglight/comments/88e4ht/remove_the_timer_at_the_end_of_prison_heist/dx0tom5?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x)</sup>

### It seems **you lose everything you collected on the Island itself.**

---

By the way, the **timer's duration** is dependent on the difficulty: the default value seemed to be 30 seconds, which was later changed to 60 seconds, while difficulties Hard and Nightmare crank it up to 2 and 3 minutes respectively, depending on the time it took the player to get there.
These parameters also change the tier of the items you are able to loot:

> The best reward (Guru) is achievable under 8 minutes on Normal mode,
>   under 15 on Hard and under 25 on Nightmare. However, if it's your first
>   or one of the very first few runs, you'll most likely end up with very
>   long time, that's normal, the more you play the better and faster you
>   do.
>   <sup>[source](https://steamcommunity.com/app/239140/discussions/0/1733210552656467483/#c1733210552656527915)</sup>

[Here](https://forum.techland.pl/topic/16246-prison-heist-complete-details/) is a wonderfully in-depth overview.

Comment: I read the tutorial from which the first comment is and the "lose everything" was what prompted me to ask this question.

Answer (score 1):

You lose only the items you looted. Your other items are safe. It would be way too cruel the other way :)